# rest API - send product translations for store-view

Tags: magento2, rest-api

We've setup in Magento a website with multiple store-views for translations.

The products and translations are stored in Microsoft Navision and will be transfered to Magento by using the rest API.

We're looking for an approach to send the translations (like different product names for the SKUs) from Navision to Magento by using some store-view identifier.

Is this approach working in Magento:

POST or PUT /rest/<store_code>/V1/products

default store:     /rest/default/V1/products/sku

german store-view: /rest/german/V1/products/sku

english store-view: /rest/english/V1/products/sku

Thx for help.

Regards Georg

Answer (score 0):

yes, you got it right :) but the request is only **PUT** if you use the endpoint `/rest/<store_code>/V1/products` to create or update products. So basically you just have to adjust the store code in your request URL and keep the same SKU.

The payload can be as simple as this (SKU is not required in the payload if your product already exists):

```
{
  "product": {
    "name": "Joust Duffle Bag for test store"     
    }
}
```